# Storing BSONObj object in std::vector crashes with big documents

Tags: c++, mongodb, stdvector

I have the following fragment of code, that accumulates BSON documents from a query cursor, to be processed afterwards:

```
// Accumulate
std::vector<BSONObj> results;
while (cursor->more()) {
  BSONObj r = cursor->nextSafe();
  results.push_back(r);
}
...
// Process it (example)
for (unsigned int ix = 0; ix < results.size(); ix++) {
  BSONElement be = results[ix].getField("_id");
  // Do somtething with 'be'
  ...
}
```

This code has worked well from a time (months) but we have recently found that with large documents in DB (around 1.1MB) the `results[ix].getField("_id")` statement crashes with segfault. This is the top of backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  readNative<int> (offset=0, t=<synthetic pointer>, this=<optimized out>) at src/mongo/base/data_view.h:46
#1  readNative<int> (offset=0, this=<optimized out>) at src/mongo/base/data_view.h:53
#2  readLE<int> (offset=0, this=<optimized out>) at src/mongo/base/data_view.h:59
#3  objsize (this=0x7f74340022e0) at src/mongo/bson/bsonobj.h:309
#4  BSONObjIterator (jso=..., this=<synthetic pointer>) at src/mongo/bson/bsonobjiterator.h:42
#5  mongo::BSONObj::getField (this=0x7f74340022e0, name=...) at src/mongo/bson/bsonobj.cpp:635
...
```

I have solved the problem using `results.push_back(r.copy())` instead of `results.push_back(r)`. Thus, probably the error was caused when the `r` object is destroyed at the end of the `while` block scope, leaving the copy pushed back in the vector in an unstable state. Pushing back a copy of `r` without hitting the block scope as a new variable seems to solve the problem.

So, I have the following questions:

1. What is the best way of storing BSONObj got from a query result in a `std::vector`? I think I have found a reasonable solution, but not sure if this is the best one.
2. Why the code using `push_back(r)` works with small documents? If the right way is to use `r.copy()` to avoid problems destroying `r` at the end of `while` block scope, I understand it should fail always, not only in the case of objects of around 1.1MB.

I'm using MongoDB C++ driver legacy-1.0.7 (in the case it may help or the problem could be related with specific versions of MongoDB C++ driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BSONObj objects returned by nextSafe do not own their data, and are invalidated by subsequent calls to nextSafe.

So, your vector becomes populated with invalid BSONObj objects.

Instead, call BSONObj::getOwned() on the cursor result before pushing back in the vector.

If you run your program under AddressSanitizer or valgrind, you will almost certainly see use-after-free type errors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So you mean using `results.push_back(r);` instead of `results.push_back(r.copy());` *but* using `r.getOwned();` just before `results.push_back(r);`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, just `results.push_back(r.getOwned())` should do the trick.

Comment: To elaborate, the BSONObj::copy method always makes a copy, but BSONObj::getOwned() only makes a copy if `r` doesn't own the buffer. So, in this case they are equivalent. But using getOwned is better practice as it will avoid needless copies in the case where you already own the document.

Comment: As to why it only fails with bigger objects - a use-after-free is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.